# Can we use PM2 to scale a node js webserver? What about port?

Tags: node.js, webserver, pm2

My question could be yet answered, but I couldn't find a precise answer to my specific question.

Imagine I have simple node.js app that start a webserver listining on port 3000

Is it at all possibile to  instruct Pm2 to auto start new processes in case of excessive load?

If yes, what happen to listening port? I mean: if I start a second webserver on the same port, it cannot works. How could we handle this problemi in pm2 ?

Comment: you could run 2 processes and have an load balancer infront of it with round robin technique

Comment: Does pm2 do this? I specifically asked for pm2

Comment: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/cluster-mode/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be this video can help you to find out your solution for this problem

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6xIbVPyh9wo

> The cluster mode allows networked Node.js applications
> (http(s)/tcp/udp server) to be scaled across all CPUs available,
> without any code modifications. This greatly increases the performance
> and reliability of your applications, depending on the number of CPUs
> available.

Comment: Do not reply with only a link. It could be not valid in a while.